# get value from request header in http call -mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-component, mule-module-jpa

I am developing a mule application. My start point is http. I need to authenticate my http calls using an authentication token which I am sending as request header. Now, How do I get this request header value in my Mule application?

Comment: Are you using oauth authentication ?? Pls share your flow you are trying ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

suppose if the header name was "authToken" which contains the authentication token.
it can be accessed in mule floe with below mel expression
`#[message.inboundProperties.authToken]`

Answer (score 1):

Alternately, if your header is 'authToken' you can use use following expression to get your header :-

```
<logger message="#[message.inboundProperties.get('authToken')]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

or

```
<logger message="#[message.inboundProperties.'authToken']" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

or

```
<logger message="#[message.inboundProperties['authToken']]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```